# JavaScript: BarChart populate data using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, bar-chart, morris.js

Hello there I have a problem populating javascript barchart from my database I am using a morris.js barchart the code of my
html is below:

```
<div class="chart" id="bar-chart" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

the javascript:

```
  <script>
  

$(function () {
  "use strict";    
  //BAR CHART
  var month = <?php echo json_encode($result_array, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
  var salary = <?php echo json_encode($result_array2, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
  var bar = new Morris.Bar({
      element: 'bar-chart',
      resize: true,
      data: [
        {y: month, a: salary},

       ]
      ,
      barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a'],
      labels: ['Date', 'Total'],
      hideHover: 'auto'

  });
  
  
});
```

The PHP code:

```
  <?php 
   $q  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM salary_logs 
   ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5");
    $result_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
   {
     $result_array[] = $row['month'];
     $result_array2[] = $row['salary'];
     echo json_encode($result_array, JSON_HEX_TAG);
   }
  ?>
```

The data in my database are :

> month: january , february
>
> salary: 1000,2000

Is there any way to create a loop that will automatically add those data?
Example the next month data will be :

> month: january, february, march
>
> salary: 1000, 2000, 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Easy way to do this** (maybe not the perfect solution but works fine and easy to handle) -

> Declare a php variable for chart data (above while loop) like - `$chart_data = '';`

Next inside the **while loop** do -

```
$chart_data = ''; // variable for chart data

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ y: '" . $row['month'] . "', a: " . $row['salary'] . " },";
}
```

> Now `echo $chart_data` inside JavaScript function. like-

```
data: [ <?php echo $chart_data; ?> ],
```

> Full JavaScript Function

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    //BAR CHART
    var month = <?php echo json_encode($result_array, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
    var salary = <?php echo json_encode($result_array2, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
    var bar = new Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar-chart',
        resize: true,

        data: [ <?php echo $chart_data; ?> ],

        barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a'],
        labels: ['Date', 'Total'],
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In moris.js chart, do the data rows (in your case month, salary) need to be javascript arrays?

So without the php part it would be something like this:

var month = ["january", "february"];
var salary = [1000, 2000];

?

Comment: without the php code the js will be like this:

var bar = new Morris.Bar({
        element: 'bar-chart',
        resize: true,
        data: [{y:"january",a:1000},{y:"january",a:1000}],
        barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
        xkey: 'y',
        ykeys: ['a'],
        labels: ['Date', 'Total'],
        hideHover: 'auto'

    });

Comment: I see...
in this case myabe not the cleanest, but a fully doable option is to leave the JSON ecnoding and simply print into the js code with the PHP.
Like this:
...

Comment: Sorry, here:

data:
[
<?php 
$q  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM salary_logs 
   ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
   {
     print "{y:" . $row['month'] . ",a:" . $row['salary'] ."}";
   }
?>
]

Comment: Look at the solution of S M Monjurul Islam! It is pretty much the same as mine, just better explained.

Comment: any link of it?

Comment: thank you I just lost a quotation haha your solution works